# Search value from one file and replace that to other file

Tags: shell, awk

So I have in Linux:

file1.txt:

```
Owner=XYZ;Language=English
Owner=XYY;Language=English
Owner=XAA;Language=Swedish
.
.
.
```

file2.txt:

```
Owner=XYZ;Language=English;Country=Russia
Owner=XYY;Language=Finnish;Country=Finland
Owner=XAA;Language=Swedish;Country=Norway
.
.
.
```

I want to find all Owner's Languages from file1.txt and Replace those to other file file2.txt (update those to be correct).  The order of lines can vary and lines also contains other fields like Country=Russia etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F";" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$NF;next} ($1 in a){$2=a[$1]} 1' OFS=";" file1.txt file2.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Owner=XYZ;Language=English;Country=Russia
Owner=XYY;Language=English;Country=Finland
Owner=XAA;Language=Swedish;Country=Norway
```

Comment: @PetriPanula, it should print the values, it will not change the file. Are you sure your actual files are same as shown samples? It worked for me for shown samples.

Comment: Yes it prints but don't change anything:

Comment: @PetriPanula, check my post now, you want to take languages from `file2.txt` to `file1.txt` then edited willl work.

Comment: I actually mean that second file file2.txt can also contain other fields also like Country=Russia   for example: "Owner=XYY;Language=Finnish;Country=Russia" and I only want to update Language field from file1.txt.. Sorry for confusion!!

Comment: @PetriPanula, please POST samples(proper samples) in your post in CODE TAGS and then let me know.

Comment: @PetriPanula, please check now?

Comment: Yes this seems to work now.. I need to test this more in Our production environment!